# Using a bash variable in regex replace

Tags: regex, perl

```
replace="bar"
echo foo123 | perl -p -e 's/(\d+)/${replace}456/'
```

Is there a way to use a pre-defined variable in your replacement string? Maybe even a better alternative to `perl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
replace="bar"  
echo foo123 | perl -p -e 's/(\d+)/$ENV{replace}456/'
```

This grabs the shell variable from the environment in which Perl runs.  In some circumstances you might need to export first:

```
export replace="bar"
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to export `replace` to the environment, `echo foo123 | replace="$replace" perl -p -e 's/(\d+)/$ENV{replace}456/'`.